# How to fix this Unity script with the MissingReferenceException error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script does the following tasks.

1. Creates a new material
2. Assign textures to the new material from `Assets/Textures/{model_name}/`
3. Save the new material in `Assets/Materials/{model_name}/{model_name}.mat`
4. Assign the new material to the importing model.
5. Adds the `MeshCollider` component and disables `MeshRenderer` to objects that contain `collider` in the importing object's child name.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

public class Importer: AssetPostprocessor
{

  // Define objTransform at the class level
  private Transform objTransform;
  private Transform materialTransform;

  void OnPostprocessModel(GameObject obj)
  {

    // Store the Transform of the GameObject
    objTransform = obj.transform;
    // Assign the value of objTransform to materialTransform
    materialTransform = objTransform;

    // Create a new material
    Material newMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));

    // Load all textures from the model's folder in the 'textures' folder
    string[] textureFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine("Assets/Textures", obj.name), "*.png");

    foreach (string textureFile in textureFiles)
    {
      // Get the filename without the extension
      string textureName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textureFile);

      // Load the texture
      Texture2D texture = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Texture2D>(textureFile);

      // Split the texture name into parts
      string[] parts = textureName.Split('_');

      // Check if the texture's name contains the object's name
      if (parts.Length > 2 && parts[0] == obj.name)
      {
        // Get the type of the texture
        string type = parts[2];

        // Assign the texture to the corresponding slot in the material
        if (type == "Albedo")
        {
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
        }
        else if (type == "Metallic")
        {
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_MetallicGlossMap", texture);
        }
        else if (type == "Normal" || type == "NormalGL")
        {
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_BumpMap", texture);
        }
        else if (type == "Height")
        {
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_ParallaxMap", texture);
        }
        else if (type == "Occlusion")
        {
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_OcclusionMap", texture);
        }
        else if (type == "Emission")
        {
          newMaterial.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
          newMaterial.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.BakedEmissive;
          newMaterial.SetTexture("_EmissionMap", texture);
        }
      }
    }

    string materialDirectory = Path.Combine("Assets/Materials", obj.name);

    // Check if the directory exists, if not, create it
    if (!Directory.Exists(materialDirectory))
    {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(materialDirectory);
    }

    // Store the name of the object
    string objName = obj.name;

    // Apply collider component to the model
    ApplyCollider(objTransform);

    // Delay the creation of the asset until after the import process has finished
    EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>
    {
      // Use the stored object name
      string materialDirectory = Path.Combine("Assets/Materials", objName);

      // Check if the directory exists, if not, create it
      if (!Directory.Exists(materialDirectory))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(materialDirectory);
      }

      // Save the material to a file
      AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(newMaterial, Path.Combine(materialDirectory, objName + ".mat"));

      // Refresh the AssetDatabase to make sure the new material appears in the editor
      AssetDatabase.Refresh();

      // Apply the new material to the model and its children
      ApplyMaterial(materialTransform, newMaterial);
    };

  }

  void ApplyCollider(Transform obj)
  {
    if (obj.name.ToLower().Contains("collider"))
      obj.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

    foreach (Transform child in obj)
    {
      if (child.name.ToLower().Contains("collider"))
      {
        child.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        ApplyCollider(child);
      }
      else
      {
        ApplyCollider(child);
      }
    }
  }

  void ApplyMaterial(Transform obj, Material newMaterial)
  {
    // Set the material for the MeshRenderer component if it exists
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    if (meshRenderer != null)
    {
      meshRenderer.material = newMaterial;
    }

    foreach (Transform child in obj)
    {
      if (child.name.ToLower().Contains("LOD"))
      {
        ApplyMaterial(child, newMaterial);
      }
      else
      {
        ApplyMaterial(child, newMaterial);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error.

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

Comment: The exception message, does it contain line information?

Comment: yes, line: 133 `MeshRenderer meshRenderer = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();`

Comment: [Please note](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessModel.html) that the GameObjects, AnimationClips and Meshes only exist during the import and will be destroyed immediately afterwards.

Comment: as @shingo hints the issue lies in you shifting the rest of execution into `EditorApplication.delayCall` - a moment when the import is already done and the objects all unloaded

Comment: I have to call `EditorApplication.delayCall` because it doesn't allow `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset()` and `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` while importing assets.